# How do I add a Transform to a List in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add a randomly generated transform to a list.
Doing the following gives me a runtime error saying NullReferenceException at the 5th line.
What am I doing wrong? Also is there a better way to add a Transform to a list? Sorry if I made any mistakes as this is my first time on Stack Overflow.

```
start()
{
  GameObject createdObject = new GameObject();
  createdObject.transform.position = new Vector3(5f, 5f, 5f);
  waypoints.Add(createdObject.transform);
}
```

Comment: I would expect that if they all have the same parent, then you can just transform the parent.  Otherwise you're probably looking at a loop:  _for each waypoint in the list_ ... _transform that waypoint_.

Comment: No, I mean the waypoints.Add line gives me a NullReferenceException

Comment: `waypoints` is null? That seems like [your first problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, Thanks to @Wyck.

Previously:

```
    private List<Transform> waypoints;
```

Changed to:

```
    private List<Transform> waypoints = new List<Transform>();
```

Comment: Since this is your first time on Stack Overflow, I'll let you know that we don't need this answer here.  Yours is a duplicate question.  And if you had searched the web for NullReferenceException you likely would have found that information. 
 NullReferenceExceptions are well understood problems with C# programs.  This post is not the place that people should be coming to for that information.  I'm glad you fixed your problem though.  But when you have a null reference exception, the way to remedy the problem is well established and discussed already elsewhere on this site.